# How to send a request including AWS SNS MessageAttributes with AWS services CodeDeploy and CodePipeline

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have learned how to use AWS services CodeDeploy and CodePipeline to send requests containing AWS SNS MessageAttributes to AWS SNS via Lambda.
However, I would like to know how to make a request containing MessageAttributes using only CodeDeploy or CodePipeline without using Lambda if possible.
There is a way to format the data sent from CodeDeploy and CodePipeline to AWS SNS with EventBridge, but is it possible to include MessageAttributes that way?